# Does pkill kill itself (and its parent processes) last?

Tags: linux, bash, process, kill

I'm writing a bash script that kills a bunch of processes selected by certain criteria and then quits. The only problem is that those criteria apply to the script and its parent processes (`bash`, `sshd`) itself, so in order to avoid killing the script before it has done its work, I first get the matching processes with `ps`, then filter out the script and its parents with `sed` and finally kill the remaining processes with `kill`.

Now I'm wondering whether I could simplify this to a single `pkill` call, but obviously that can only work if `pkill` is guaranteed to kill itself and its parent processes *last* if they occur in the list of processes to kill.

Is there such a guarantee implemented into `pkill`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pkill` never kills itself, just like `pgrep` nerver lists itself; `pkill` does *exit* after killing each process matching the criteria, except itself. `pkill` does kill its parent(s) if it(they) match the criteria, but if the parent is a shell unless you use an unignorable signal (usually only -9 aka -[SIG]KILL) the shell normally ignores it. If it includes your `sshd` that will indeed kill your session, and with it your shell and (most?) other processes, which is usually undesired.

You might want to use `pgrep` to *find* the processses, perhaps with `-l` or `-lf`, and do additional checks before `kill`ing them.

Comment: There is a note in the [`man`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) page confirming this too: "The running `pgrep` or `pkill` process will never report itself as a match."

Answer (score 4):

It seems that with pkill from procps-ng, `pkill -f` CAN match its own command line and kill itself, while BSD `pkill` on macOS doesn't seem to do this. *(I tested "pkill from procps-ng 3.3.17")*

See [linux - Prevent process from killing itself using pkill - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740481/prevent-process-from-killing-itself-using-pkill) for options to avoid this.